# How to update control in a thread safe way

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have a windows.form.userControl class and at run time i want to add some linklabels dynamically. When I apply this code snippet inside Load method it work perfectly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
       linkLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
       linkLabel.Name = i.ToString();
       linkLabel.Text = i.ToString();
       linkLabel.LinkClicked += new  System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(linkLabel_LinkClicked);
       this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
       linkLabel.Top = top;
       top += 30;
      }
```

But when I move this code snippet inside to ***backgroudworker*** ***doWork*** method it will give invalid operation exception related to cross thread issue in this line :-   **this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);**

How do I make this as a thread safe operation? I'm newbie to C# and I'm using C# 4.0 using VS 2010.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to synchronize the method to the UI thread. You can use the property `Control.InvokeRequired` to check if synchronization is needed and `Control.Invoke` to invoke any delegate synchronously.

```
private void AddLinkLabels()
{
    // If synchronization is needed, i.e. when this method is called on a non-UI thread, invoke the method synchronized and return immediately.
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(AddLinkLabels));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        linkLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        linkLabel.Name = i.ToString();
        linkLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        linkLabel.LinkClicked += new  System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(linkLabel_LinkClicked);
        this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
        linkLabel.Top = top;
        top += 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Florian, this line 'Invoke(AddLinkLabels);' give error saying invalid argument. any idea about that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should switch to thread that created that control in order to interact with it

Use this code to fix this

```
if(this.InvokeRequired)
   this.Invoke(new Action(() => {this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);}));
else
   this.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
```

Comment: I would call invoke with the whole method because your sample will cause ten calls to `Control.Invoke` instead of one.

Comment: It's a matter of optimization. You are right, need to avoid multiple Invokes

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Stecya can also be put into [an extension method like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656134/c-async-ping-not-work-from-a-threading-timer/4656295#4656295).

Answer (score 0):

As Stecya already said: You should switch to thread that created that control in order to interact with it. This can be done in backgroundworkers ProgressChanged event, because it works in UI thread, without need to do invoke. Sample at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc.aspx).